# How does opposite $\sin60\unicode{176}$ have $0.866\ldots$ if hypotenuse is $1\,?$

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, circles, angle, pythagorean-triples

I've approached in a few different ways to prove it, but couldn't get any good results.

When :

$d = 2\,,$

$\text{radius}=\dfrac d2\;\rightarrow\;r=1\,.$

Since hypotenuse is the same length with $\,r\,,$

$\sin(\theta)=\dfrac{\text{opp}}{\text{hyp}(r)}$

But divided by $\,1\,$ is simply meaningless, so it should be:

$\sin(\theta)=\dfrac{\text{opp}}1$

$\sin(\theta)=\text{opp}\;\;$ (still unknown)

This time, I used Pythagorean Theorem to get the other lengths directly.

By using the formula:

$c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

$c^2=a^2+b^2$

$a^2=c^2-b^2$

$a=\sqrt{c^2-b^2}$

Since $\,c\,$ represents $\,r\,,$

$a=\sqrt{r^2-b^2}$

$a=\sqrt{1^2-b^2}$

$a=\sqrt{1-b^2}\;\;$ (still unknown)

At the end, both ways couldn't find out what numbers of $\,o\,$ and $\,a\,$ are as long as hypotenuse is $\,1\,.$

But when I tap the calculator, $\,\sin\left(60\unicode{176}\right)\,$ throws $\,0.866025\ldots\,$ which doesn't make sense.

If I given only hypotenuse length, how can I prove that $\,\sin(\theta)=x\,?$

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144351/discussion-on-question-by-l3lue-how-does-opposite-sin60-unicode176-have-0); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned by @lulu, I would construct a $30-60-90$ triangle on the unit circle first.
After we obtain all side lengths, we can use $\sin(\alpha) = \frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hypotenuse}}$ to prove the value of $\sin(60°)$.

We first construct the triangle $\triangle ABC$, noting that the segment $AB$ has to be of length $1$, since that is the radius of the unit circle. By mirroring $\triangle ABC$ on the $x$-axis, we obtain $\triangle ACD$, noting that the segment $AD$ has to be of length $1$ too, for the same reason as above.
We now have a larger triangle $\triangle ABD$.

Notice that all the angles of $\triangle ABD$ are $60°$, that means $\triangle ABD$ is equilateral.
Thus, the side length of segment $BD$ is 1.

Since $BD$ is exactly twice the length of $BC$, we know that $BC$ is of length $\frac{1}{2}$.
Also, since $AB$ is of length 1, we know that $AC = \sqrt{1^2 - \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2} = \sqrt{\frac{3}{4}} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Now, $\sin(60°) = \frac{AC}{1} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Comment: I would put one side of the equilateral triangle on the $x$ axis and the opposite vertex at $(\cos(60^\circ), \sin(60^\circ))$ to really make use of the unit circle.

Comment: Sorry for being idle long time. I was wondering about how computer calculated sin functions but my limited vocabulary couldn't appeal this. By watching ton of videos on Youtube and googling. I understood how the sin is calculated between human and computer differently. Thanks to all the people for answering and comments.

Answer (score 0):

You may be thinking side-$a$ is the opposite. If you treat side-$a\,$ as the $\,x$-axis and side-$b\,$ as the
$y$-axis, then side-$b\,$ will give you the
$\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}=0.866$ you expect.